# Tap event on map element is not working

Tags: c#, maps, windows-phone-8

Here is my code

```
public GeoCoordinateCollection AddCirclePath(GeoCoordinate geoCoordinate, Color stroke, double strokeThickness)
{ 
    Point geoPoint = map.ConvertGeoCoordinateToViewportPoint(geoCoordinate);
    MapPolygon polyCircle = new MapPolygon();
    polyCircle.FillColor = Color.FromArgb(250, 220, 220, 0);
    polyCircle.StrokeColor = stroke;
    polyCircle.StrokeThickness = strokeThickness;
    polyCircle.StrokeDashed = false;
    polyCircle.Path = MapUtils.CreateCircle(geoCoordinate, geoCoordinate.HorizontalAccuracy);
    map.MapElements.Add(polyCircle);

    //click event
    GestureListener gestureListener = GestureService.GetGestureListener(polyCircle);
    gestureListener.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(CircleTapped);

    return polyCircle.Path;
}

private void CircleTapped(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Logger.Log("Circle tapped");
}
```

I add circle on map using above code but I'm unable to get tap event on this map element. I'm using `Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map` class for map

Comment: Hi Inder, were you able to solve this problem? I'm running into the same dilemma where the "CircleTapped" gesture method never gets fired. I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: No this didn't work for me. I choose a way around, what I did is get the tap point then converted it into geo point the checked which circle contains that point...

Answer (score 0):

There's several bugs in the control and hit testing. One solution is sometimes to add the last vextex in your element twice (I know it doesn't make sense but I've seen this resolve tap issues with polylines, so I'm guessing it's the same with polygon). It could also be that your ring orientation is wrong (clockwise vs counterclockwise)

Answer (score 0):

(This is quite old post but in case someone else is looking for solution, here's a simple example.)

You should be able to use API directly to get the tapped map element w/o any conversions or workarounds.

Add a polygon.

```
var collection = new GeoCoordinateCollection();
collection.Add(new GeoCoordinate(0d, 0d));
collection.Add(new GeoCoordinate(10d, 0d));
collection.Add(new GeoCoordinate(10d, 10d));
collection.Add(new GeoCoordinate(0d, 10d));
collection.Add(new GeoCoordinate(0d, 0d));

var poly = new MapPolygon();
poly.FillColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 255, 0, 0);
poly.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
poly.StrokeThickness = 15;
poly.Path = collection;
Map.MapElements.Add(poly);
```

And catch the tap.

```
private void Map_OnTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var point = e.GetPosition(Map);
    //var coordinate = Map.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(point);

    int elements = Map.GetMapElementsAt(point).Count;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Hit {0} map element(s)", elements));
}
```

Bug regarding polylines does not apply to polygons, you do not need to add the last point twice. You should still have same starting- and ending points to keep the polygon closed (although this is not mandatory, either). Ring orientation does not seem to affect wether element is selectable or not.